# validate user name-best regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I came across this username guidelines from google

- Usernames can contain letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), dashes (-), underscores (_), apostrophes ('), and periods (.).
- Usernames can't contain an ampersand (&), equal sign (=), brackets (<,>), plus sign (+), comma (,), or more than one period (.) in a row.
- Usernames can begin or end with non-alphanumeric characters, with a maximum of 64 characters.

(https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en ) .

When I am trying to validate usernames for my app with jQuery validate. I manged to achieve others except to detect two periods. Following is the regex I used.

```
/^[a-z0-9_.-]+$/i
```

How i can modify this to achieve those requirements.or is there any alternatives than using a single regular expression?

Comment: is that the final regex for google guideline or are you making checks one by one ?

Comment: Negation with Regular Expressions are done in different ways. For this type of checks you need [negative lookaheads.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind#t=201609141316050207877)

Comment: @SimonPA this is the regex i tried to achieve as the final regex.is it better to do like this or doing multiple checks?

Comment: some down-voted this question is it too stupid question or should i remove this?i learned a lot on regex with this question though!

Comment: Don't remove it. There are a lot of haters around here :) Don't pay attention to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
/^(?!.*\.\.)[\w.-]{6,64}$/
```

( The `6` is some improv from me, assuming you'll want a minimum username length ;) )

It uses a negative looka-head to make sure there aren't two consecutive `.`, and then matches 6-64 allowed characters (`\w` matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _).

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hL1hE7/1).